# Foreach Pipe Return Types

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure my title is the best descriptor of my issue.  Consider this minimum working example:

```
$arr = @()

$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Name –Value "Fred"
$object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Rank –Value "2"

$arr += $object

$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Name –Value "Joe"
$object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Rank –Value "1"

$arr += $object

$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Name –Value "Ann"
$object | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Rank –Value "4"

$arr += $object

$arr

($arr | foreach { if($_.Rank -gt 1) { $_ } }).GetType() | FT
($arr | foreach { if($_.Rank -le 1) { $_ } }).GetType() | FT
```

The output of this is

```
Name Rank
---- ----
Fred 2   
Joe  1   
Ann  4   



IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType    
-------- -------- ----     --------    
True     True     Object[] System.Array



IsPublic IsSerial Name           BaseType     
-------- -------- ----           --------     
True     False    PSCustomObject System.Object
```

My problem exists when trying to do additional processing on the resultant array of the foreach commands.  As you can imagine, the input data for $arr would be different each time and the number of matching results would be different. Depending on the number of matching results the data type is different.  **What I would like is for both of these to return an array of objects** but in the case where there is only one match it returns just the object.  If I try to use a calculated index to get information from the array I will get vastly different results depending on if it is an object or an array of objects.

Hoping someone has a solution for me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the expression with `@()`:

```
@($arr | foreach { if($_.Rank -le 1) { $_ } }).GetType() | FT
```

This will always result in an array.

Comment: Thank you!  This simply and perfectly solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can either handle this inside whatever function emits 1 or more objects by using `WriteObject` and specifying the `enumerateCollection` parameter:

```
function Get-ArrayOfThings
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateRange(1,100)]
        [int]$Count = 3
    )

    $PSCmdlet.WriteObject(@(1..$Count), $false)
}
(Get-ArrayOfThings -Count 5).GetType() # shows System.Object[]
(Get-ArrayOfThings -Count 1).GetType() # still System.Object[]
```

or you can enforce it in on the caller side with an array subexpression:

```
$ArrayOfOneOrMoreThings = @($OneOrMoreThings)
```